# Document Checklist for OCI for minor child born in the US

Tags: usa, h1-visa, indian-citizens

I am applying for OCI (Overseas Citizen of India) for a minor child. I see 2 different checklists on VFS website for *"New OCI for Minor"*.

- One of them requires us to send the Original US Passport, whereas the other just needs us to send a self-attested copy of the passport.
- Both are titled `NEW OCI Checklist - For MINOR`.

How are we supposed to know which instruction to follow? There is no versioning or date in the checklist to find out which is really the latest. Links to the two checklists:

https://www.vfsglobal.com/one-pager/india/united-states-of-america/oci-services/pdf/oci-checklist-minor-final.pdf
https://visa.vfsglobal.com/one-pager/india/united-states-of-america/oci-services/pdf/new-oci-minor-checklist.pdf

I have posted a query on the VFS website, but have not heard back on that yet. Wondering if anyone has applied for it recently and can help.

---

VFS has a typo in the response to submitting the query on their website. Here is what it says:

> Request **Submited** successfully. Your Reference No. xxxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this reply from VFS Global. As per that we just need to enclose the Self attested photocopy of the US Passport.

> From: info.ihcusacs@vfshelpline.com
>
> Dear Customer,
>
> Thank you for contacting the VFS Indian Visa, Passport & OCI
> Application Center Help Desk in the United States.
>
> We understand that you have a query in regards to the document
> checklist.
>
> As per the latest update for New OCI you need to enclose the Self
> attest photocopy of a US Passport.
>
> Please refer the below link to get the clarity on document checklist:
> https://services.vfsglobal.com/one-pager/india/united-states-of-america/oci-services/pdf/oci-checklist-minor-final.pdf
>
> In case of any further assistance, please feel free to reply to the
> same email or call us on +1800 320 9693 and we will be glad to assist
> you.
>
> Best Regards,
>
> <VFS Representative's Name>
>
> VFS Indian Consular application Centre – United States of America
>
> VFS GLOBAL

---

**EDIT:**
As per the latest documents required by VFS, we no longer have to send the original US Passport for OCI.